# Some of my keys are automatically being pressed along with other keys

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, keyboard

### History

The last time when my computer shutdown was a power failure. Now some keys are automatically being pressed when I type something.

The last thing I did to keyboard setting was adding a keyboard layout (on Ubuntu).

### What is happening

Whenever I press <kbd>c</kbd>, `xc` is writeen

<kbd>s</kbd> gives me `sd`
<kbd>d</kbd> gives me `sd`

<kbd>e</kbd> gives me `we`

<kbd>2</kbd> gives me `23`, So when I want <kbd>@</kbd> it gives me `@#`
<kbd>3</kbd> gives me `23`

Pressing <kbd>CAPS Lock</kbd> gives me <kbd>F3</kbd> and vice-versa.

All other key are either working fine or I don't use them.

I have two operating system Ubuntu and Windows, I use Windows very less and found this problem on Ubuntu, but as soon as I logged in to Windows (for checking) then I found that Windows has the same problem.

### Effects on my life

- This starts form the time of login, even I have problem in typing my password.
- Whenever I try to save any webpage, it is bookmarked automatically.
- Whenever I copy, it is cut automatically.
- I have to spend more than half of time correcting what I have typed.

*Note: Typing thisd quwesdtion wasd rweally a big pain to mwe.*

Comment: Is it a wired or wireless keyboard?

Comment: @Ali wired, actually USB..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a hardware issue to me. I've had this several times in the past, and just replaced the keyboard. It could just be a piece of debris on one of the tracks. Do you have a spare around to check?

Comment: Will cleaning the circuit board (which is made up of transparent material) will work?

Comment: Which keyboard is it? It should work, but you need to isolate this as the problem first.

Comment: its **SSD-KB-806**

Comment: Did you get a chance to try another?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a broken keyboard.
You need to connect another keyboard to your computer and check if it works OR
connect this keyboard to another computer or laptop and check if it shows the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I forgot to mention that a few months ago my drink was poured into the keyboard, after a 2-3 days my keyboard became home of a group of ants.

For getting rid from that I opened up my keyboard and cleaned it well, and finally sprayed an (liquid) ant repellent inside and outside of keyboard. I cleaned the excessive repellent as well, and screwed it up.

But I forgot that that transparent circuit board has three layers. And I just cleaned the outer layers leaving two layers wet which was doing short circuit.

In my case cleaning that liquid was the answer which was doing a short circuit I think. Now my keyboard it working fine like before. But one thing I'm still not getting is why it didn't just happened when I sprayed the repellent.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm having the same issue recently. I thought problem was a bit of moisture underneath  the keys. So I've tried full dissassembly and cleaning on my keyboard but the problem was actually fixed but it was temporary. After couple hours RIP to my keyboard again. I think the only solution is to buy a new one

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this problem with a Logitech K360 keyboard today. When I press some keyboard keys, one or multiple other keys are registering as being pressed as well. Basically multiple keys are being pressed at the same time, when I'm only actually pressing a single key. (For me it was: when I pressed D, B, Down or Asterisk, it would register as my having simultaneously also pressed Page Up.)

If you're seeing a **consistent pattern** like this, i.e. when you press *certain* keys it *always* registers as your having also pressed some specific other key(s), then you've almost certainly got a **short circuit inside the keyboard hardware**.

## How to fix it

These kinds of short circuits can be fixed – you don't need to buy a new keyboard. Fixing it may be easier than you think.

Certainly in the case of Logitech's K360, the internal circuitry is nothing more than 3 sheets of plastic, which you can wipe clean. Many other keyboards use a similar system.

1. Look up how to open your keyboard. Turn it off and remove batteries first.
2. Carefully wipe down the plastic circuit layers. Look for signs where dirt has got in, or moisture has caused marks. Use a microfibre cloth with a very small amount of cleaning fluid to gently wipe these marks away. Use a dry cloth to give the whole thing a final clean wipe on all sides of all plastic layers.
3. While you're at it, give the internals a bit of a clean.
4. Put it back together.